# unable to fetch JSON from a CDN link

Tags: json, api, fetch-api, cdn, squarespace

I am a begginer with JS. I am deploying Bullhorn app on a Squarespace website. Squarespace does not provide the luxury to add app.JSON files into it.

I am so created respository on Github and added the cdn links into the site:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Muhammad-waqas732/Ripple-Effect-Recruitment@latest/runtime-es2015.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Muhammad-waqas732/Ripple-Effect-Recruitment@latest/runtime-es5.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Muhammad-waqas732/Ripple-Effect-Recruitment@latest/polyfills-es5.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Muhammad-waqas732/Ripple-Effect-Recruitment@latest/polyfills-es2015.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Muhammad-waqas732/Ripple-Effect-Recruitment@latest/main-es2015.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Muhammad-waqas732/Ripple-Effect-Recruitment@latest/main-es5.js

My respository is [this](https://github.com/Muhammad-waqas732/Ripple-Effect-Recruitment).

Now the code for fetching the (it's in: https://github.com/Muhammad-waqas732/Ripple-Effect-Recruitment/blob/main/main-es2015.js) is:

this.http.get("./app.json") [Whole code is too big to qoute it's in the respository]

which is unable to fetch API as there is no "/app.json" on the Squarespace website.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I hosted the bullhorn app on a new server and used that iframe on my Squarespace site